# AngularJS set route without template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an app that has a sidebar that I want to perform actions with different controllers and different hashed URL's.

For example, I'd want `/edit/item` to use an `EditItemController` which would set a scope property that is used in an `ng-switch` to determine which view to load within the sidebar.

The same is true for `/edit/item/details`, this would use an `EditItemDetailsController` and slide the sidebar open and display the view `ng-include` from the switch.

The problem is that everything I've found seems like you can't have a route without a template.  So, I can do this with having `ng-click` and just use the switch for the views, but then I don't get to save the state within the browser, which isn't ideal.

I've tried defining my routes with `template: ''` but this doesn't work, it actually renders an empty template.

Is there anyway to work around this, to set URL's for specific controllers, without effecting the main ng-view?  Also, without using `ui-router`.

Thank you

Comment: Can you copy the app.js in a gist file ?

Comment: You can save the state in `$rootScope` or some configuration service.